# How to use same prop for different select fields separately in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a vue component in which I am using one prop(object) in multiple select fields

Inside select fields I am changing some data which is bind with v-model separately but whenever I change data in it, it reflects in other fields too. How to stop this reactive nature.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" v-for="day in parseInt(location.days)" :key="day">
  Day {{day}}-{{preselect(day,defaultt,location.id,place)}}
  <v-select 
    v-model="days[day]"  
    name="addplaceloc"                     
    label="title" @input="addtoplaces(day,location.id)"                      
    :value="defaultt" :options="place"  multiple  />

    <div  v-for="(placeinfo, index) in objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place']">
      Place: {{placeinfo['title']}}:{{objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['id']}}-->{{index}}->{{day}}

      <label>From:</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['from_time']" >

      <label>To:</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['to_time']">

      <label>Remark:</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['remark']">
      <button @click="run"> yess</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code I have multiple cities with multiple days with multiple places selected on a particular day .

> for example city A have 2 days.
>
> day 1 I have selected place1 and on day 2 I have selected same place1.

Each day we have 3 fields: to_time, from_time, remark for each place selected in that day . Now when I change day 1 to_time it reflects on day 2's.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9rQA.png)

Comment: Can you share the script as welll fro the above code, if possible create a codepen, that would really help to solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

First of all, components should not update props.

Refer:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

They should copy them during init, and update the copies.

Then possibly on some action like clicking on 'Save' button, or on blur, the component should emit the data as part of an event - say 'input' or 'change' event.

Refer:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

**Edit - After the code and image were added:**

You have to get your data structures right. And also, I recommend keeping your "master data" separate from your instance data.

List of cities is master data. List of places is master data. You keep them separate. You can keep a separate object mapping the details together into something like a TripSchedule entity.

For example:

One schedule or trip plan =>

```
{
   city_id1: {
       date1_ddmmyyyy: [place_id1a, placeid1b],
       date2_ddmmyyyy: [place_id1c, placeid1d]
   },
   city_id2: {
       date3_ddmmyyyy: [place_id2a, placeid2b]
   }
}
```

Or, even better..

```
{
   date1_ddmmyyyy:[
       {city: city_id1, place: place_id1a},
       {city: city_id1, place: place_id1b}
   ],date2_ddmmyyyy:[
       {city: city_id1, place: place_id1c}
   ],
   date3_ddmmyyyy:[
       {city: city_id2, place: place_id2a},
       {city: city_id2, place: place_id2b}
   ]
}
```

So, basically, don't store the trip plan inside the city or place.

Comment: thanks for your reply I just implement what you have said but my problem remains the same , now I am using local variable for my select tag but when I do some change in one element it reflect on other element's value also, like some how value are reactivity connected to each other . how can I assign a same value(object) to different v-models independently ?

Comment: If you want many components to refer something and not change it, use props. If you want many components to update their own copies of it, clone the data and give clones to each component.

Comment: It will be easier if you can post actual code.. Or create a sample to show your problem

Comment: I am trying to clone data for each element but how to do that?
they all are following single source of truth

Comment: @DevanshDeep I added some more info to the answer via Edit. I know its a bit vague, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use _.cloneDeep() loadash function to clone prop in local data variable and then clone again that data for each day individual. _.cloneDeep() will prevent reactivity.